# how to use redis for sorting and filtration at the same time?

Tags: performance, search, redis

Imagine: someone has a huge website selling, let's say, T-shirts.

we want to show paginated sorted listings of offers, also with options to filter by parameters, let's say - T-shirt colour.

- offers should be sortable by any of 5 properties (creating date,
  price, etc...)

  **Important requirement 1:** we have to give a user an ability to browse **all** the 15 million offers, and not just the "top-N".

  **Important requirement 2:** they must be able to jump to a **random** page at any time, not just flick through them sequentially

we use some sort of a traditional data storage (MongoDB, to be precise).

The problem is that MongoDB (as well as other traditional databases) performs poorly when it comes to big offsets. **Imagine if a user wants to fetch a page of results somewhere in the middle of this huge list sorted by creation date with some additional filters (for instance - by colour)**

There is an article describing this kind of problem:
http://openmymind.net/Paging-And-Ranking-With-Large-Offsets-MongoDB-vs-Redis-vs-Postgresql/

Okay now, so we are told that redis is a solution for similar kind of problem. You "just" need to prepare certain data structures and search them instead of your primary storage.

the question is:

**What kind of structures and approaches whould you suggest to use in order to solve this with Redis?**

Answer (score 1):

Sorted Sets, paging through with `ZRANGE`.

Comment: while for filtering you create one sorted set per filter and intersect the selected ones with ZINTERSTORE http://redis.io/commands/zinterstore

Comment: Very true, but I did try to keep within the 30 characters limit ;)

Comment: can you please tell more details? What kind of score do I assign for values in each of each filter sorted set? what kind of score is supposed to be in the set resulting from zineterstore? Do I need to time-limit this result key to save memory?